# Find distance between phrases in text

Tags: python, count, distance

I have a question, how count word between phrases in text? For example, I have the next text:

> Elon Musk is a technology entrepreneur and investor. He is the founder, CEO, and lead designer of SpaceX. Elon Musk has stated that the goals of SpaceX, Tesla, and SolarCity revolve around his vision to change the world and humanity.

And I want to count how many words are between "Elon Mask" and "SpaceX". And return smth like a list with numbers and then find average word distance. For example, [15,6].

I know, that in case of words, we can split text on words. But what to do with phrases?

Answer (score 1):

You might split your text, based on points, exclamation marks and question marks, but how will your program know the difference of a point between phrases and a point, indicating an abbreviation? In top of that, how will you deal with brackets? Will they be considered as separate phrases or not?

I don't think there's a straightforward answer to your question, unless you force some serious limitations on your phrases.

Answer (score 1):

As the user Dominique mentioned, there are a lot of small details you must account for. I've made a simple program that will find the distance of two words. You wanted to find the distance between "Elon Musk" and "SpaceX". Why not just find the distance between "Musk" and "SpaceX"?

**Note: This example will return the distance between the first occurrence of the words. In this program, we find the distance between "Musk" (2nd word) and "SpaceX (18th word). The distance *in between* is 15 words**

> Elon Musk is a technology entrepreneur and investor. He is the founder, CEO, and lead designer of SpaceX. Elon Musk has stated that the goals of SpaceX, Tesla, and SolarCity revolve around his vision to change the world and humanity.

**Example (Python 3):**

```
# Initial sentence
phrase = 'Elon Musk is a technology entrepreneur and investor. He is the founder, CEO, and lead designer of SpaceX. Elon Musk has stated that the goals of SpaceX, Tesla, and SolarCity revolve around his vision to change the world and humanity.'

# Removes common punctuation characters
phrase = ''.join(character for character in phrase if character not in ('!', '.' , ':' , ',', '"')) # Insert punctuation you want removed

# Creates a list of split words
word_list = phrase.split()

# Words you want to find the distance between (word_1 comes first in the sentence, then word_2)
word_1 = 'Musk'
word_2 = 'SpaceX'

# Calculates the distance between word_1 and word_2
distance = (word_list.index(word_2)) - (word_list.index(word_1))

# Prints distance between word_1 and word_2
print('Distance between "' + word_1 + '" and "' + word_2 + '" is ' + str(distance - 1) + ' words.')
```

**Output:**

*Distance between "Musk" and "SpaceX" is 15 words.*

Answer (score 0):

There is some logic that you haven't specified, but something like the following might do the trick:

```
def find_distance(sentence, word1, word2):
    distances = []
    while sentence != "":
        _, _, sentence = sentence.partition(word1)
        text, _, _ = sentence.partition(word2)
        if text != "":
            distances.append(len(text.split()))
    return distances
```

And if you call it with your sentence, you will get the result that you wanted `[15, 6]`

```
print(find_distance(phrase, "Elon Musk", "SpaceX"))
```

Note that the behaviour for a case like `Elon Musk is a technology Elon Musk entrepreneur ...` has to be defined. Which occurrence do you want to take? First or second?